# Factors function obtain least common multiple or prime number

Tags: javascript, arrays, factors

In the factors function, we seek to obtain the minimum denominators of the number passed by parameter or the exact prime  numbers of the given number, if we multiply all the minimum denominators the result is the number itself.
`factors(4) = [2,2] / 2x2 = 4
 factors(18) = [2,3,3] / 2x3x3 = 18
factors(3)=[3]`

For the problem i got to use recursive aproach.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please show your try.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a function generate primes in a range. Then keep dividing the number by the min prime number if the number is divisible and add that prime number to result array.

```js
function isPrime(num){
  if(num === 2) return true;
  if(num === 3) return true;
  if(num % 2 === 0 || num % 3 === 0) return false;
  for(let i = 5; i < Math.sqrt(num) + 1; i += 6){
    if(num % i === 0 || num % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
  }
  return true
}
function createPrimes(range){
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 2; i < range; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)){
      res.push(i)
    }
  }
  return res;
}


function factors(num){
  if(isPrime(num)) return [num];
  let primes = createPrimes(num);
  let res = []
  while(num !== 1){
    for(let p of primes){
      if(num % p === 0){
        res.push(p);
        num /= p;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}


console.log(factors(18))
console.log(factors(4))
console.log(factors(3))
```